# Orchard CMS ContentManager BuildDisplay very slow

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I'm fairly new to Orchard, but I feel i'm making significant progress.  I have been stuck on making my display driver more efficient and it seems building displays is the area that needs to most work.

When building displays for 30 content items, the following code takes about 30 seconds to complete.  I do not know of any other way to build a display shape for a content item or make it faster.

Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
var contentItems = _profileService.GetProfileList(profileViewOptionsDetails.filteredServices, pageNumber, profileViewOptionsDetails.PageSize, queryString);
var pager = new Pager(_siteService.GetSiteSettings(), pageNumber, pageSize);
var pagerShape = shapeHelper.Pager(pager).TotalItemCount(totalItemCount);
var list = shapeHelper.List();

foreach (var contentItem in contentItems.ContentItems)
{
    list.Add(_mcrfContentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItem.Content, "Summary"));
}

public FilterGroup GetProfileList(List<int> filterList, int page, int pageSize, string query)
    {
        IList<ProfileRoles> profileRecords = new List<ProfileRoles>();

        FilterGroup filteredProfiles = new FilterGroup();

        profileRecords = GetMcrfProfileList(filterList, query, page, pageSize);

        filteredProfiles.ProfileCount = profileRecords.Count;

        var content = GetMcrfProfileRecords(profileRecords.Select(item => item.ContentID).ToList());

        IList<ProfileListEntity> profileList = new List<ProfileListEntity>();
        foreach (var c in content)
        {
            ProfileListEntity profileListEntity = new ProfileListEntity();
            profileListEntity.Content = c;
            profileListEntity.Role = profileRecords.Where(x => x.ContentID == c.Id).Select(y => y.Role).ToList().First();
                profileList.Add(profileListEntity);
        }
        filteredProfiles.ContentItems = profileList;
        return filteredProfiles;
    }

public IEnumerable<IContent> GetMcrfProfileRecords(IList<int> contentIDs)
    {
        return _contentManager.GetMany<IContent>(contentIDs, VersionOptions.Published, QueryHints.Empty);
    }

 public class McrfProfileDriver : ContentPartDriver<McrfProfilePart>
{
    private const string TemplateName = "Parts/McrfProfile";
    private readonly IMcrfProfileService _profileService;
    private readonly IContentManager _mcrfContentManager;

    public McrfProfileDriver(IMcrfProfileService profileService, IContentManager mcrfContentManager)
    {
        _profileService = profileService;
        _mcrfContentManager = mcrfContentManager;
    }

    protected override DriverResult Display(
        McrfProfilePart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        if (displayType == "Detail")
        {                
            McrfProfileDetailViewModel profileDetailViewModel = new McrfProfileDetailViewModel();

            profileDetailViewModel.ProfileDetail = part.ProfileDetail;

            return ContentShape("Parts_McrfProfile",
                             () =>
                             {
                                 return shapeHelper.Parts_McrfProfile(ProfileDetail: profileDetailViewModel);
                             });

        }
        else
        {
            McrfProfileSummaryViewModel profileSummaryViewModel = new McrfProfileSummaryViewModel();

            //profileSummaryViewModel.ProfileImage = part.ProfileSummary.ProfileImage;
            //profileSummaryViewModel.Name = part.ProfileSummary.Name;
            //profileSummaryViewModel.JobTitle = part.ProfileSummary.JobTitle;

            profileSummaryViewModel.ProfileImage = part.ProfileDetail.ProfileImage;
            profileSummaryViewModel.Name = part.ProfileDetail.Name;
            profileSummaryViewModel.JobTitle = part.ProfileDetail.JobTitle;

            profileSummaryViewModel.ContentItem = part.ContentItem;

            return ContentShape("Parts_McrfProfile_Summary",
                             () =>
                             {
                                 return shapeHelper.Parts_McrfProfile_Summary(ProfileRecord: profileSummaryViewModel);
                             });
        }
    }

    //GET
    protected override DriverResult Editor(McrfProfilePart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_McrfProfile_Edit",
                            () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                                TemplateName: TemplateName,
                                Model: part,
                                Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    //POST
    protected override DriverResult Editor(
        McrfProfilePart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }

    public class McrfProfileHandler : ContentHandler
{
    IMcrfProfileService _profileService;

    public McrfProfileHandler(IRepository<McrfProfileRecord> repository, IMcrfProfileService profileService)
    {
        _profileService = profileService;

        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));

        OnLoading<McrfProfilePart>((context, part) => LazyLoadHandlers(part));

        OnIndexing<McrfProfilePart>((context, part) => context.DocumentIndex
            .Add("profile-detail", part.ProfileDetail.Name + " " + string.Join(", " , part.ProfileDetail.Publications.Select(e => e.Citation).ToArray())).RemoveTags().Analyze()
        .Add("profile-name", part.ProfileDetail.Name).RemoveTags().Analyze());

    }

    protected void LazyLoadHandlers(McrfProfilePart part)
    {
        // add handlers that will load content for a profile just-in-time
        part.ProfileDetailField.Loader(() => _profileService.GetProfileDetail(part.ProfileId));
        //part.ProfileSummaryField.Loader(() => _profileService.GetProfileSummary(part.ProfileId));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any custom parts attached to these content items?

Comment: That is probably what is slowing the build display method down. Try removing them and see if it gets any faster. Then try and work out what is actually wrong in your drivers. Or share the code here if you can

Comment: Hazza, thank you very much for you help thus far.  I have updated my description to include all relevant code in regards to custom parts attached to my content items i'm attempting to build faster.

Comment: If it is the builddisplay method that is slow then you will need to share the code within your Driver's display methods of your custom parts

Comment: I have also included the custom part's driver display method.  thank you.

Comment: I also included the handler class that loads the custom part's data

Comment: The problem is actually populating the custom part's data.  I need to rework this.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Combined() wrapping your your Display Shapes if more than one... and put the logic inside the anonymous method.

Do not use a clause to check for your DisplayType and let the [placement.info](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info) do its job, once you get the hang of it its quite powerful.

If you are fairly new to Orchard i will consider, going quickly through some of the documentation and download the source. You will be able to understand what and how you can be better by looking at other Part Drivers.